# Newtonsoft JsonConvert vs System.Web.Helpers Json - type cast problem

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization, asp.net-webpages

I've been using `System.Web.Helpers.Json` to deserialize objects quite successfully up until I received a json with the keys that only differ in case of the letters and the Decode() method throws an `ArgumentException`. I tried to figure out how to make this class work in case-sensitive way and couldn't, so I decided to go with Newtonsoft library instead. Json.NET works fine case-wise, however the deserialized objects it returns would require a type cast as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaseSensitivityTest() {
  string json = "{\"e\":\"executionReport\",\"E\":1616877261436}";
  dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
  string executionReport = result.e;//have to assign to a typed variable for the assert below to work
  Assert.AreEqual("executionReport", executionReport);
  Assert.IsTrue(1616877261436 == (long)result.E);//or explicitly cast to a type
  result = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(json);//System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
  Assert.IsTrue(1616877261436 == result.E);//this would've worked without any type cast as in the example below
}
```

The rest of my code relies heavily on deserialized objects having properly typed properties (e.g. my typical code `decimal.Parse(deserializedResponse.price)` expects `price` to be string and not `JValue<string>`). Here's another comparison:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TypeCastTest() {
  string json = "{\"intValue\":123}";
  dynamic webHelpersResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(json);
  dynamic newtonSoftResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
  Assert.AreEqual(123, webHelpersResult.intValue);//All good here, I want JsonConvert to work the same way
  Assert.AreEqual(123, newtonSoftResult.intValue);//Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<123 (System.Int32)>. Actual:<123 (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)>.
}
```

It would be very difficult to refactor adding type casts everywhere, so I would prefer a single point of fix. I need either to make the `System.Web.Helpers.Json` case-sensitive or `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to return .NET-typed values and not of JValue type. What would be the best way to achieve this? I'm writing a console application running on Windows 7 machine, so all fancy web/WINRT/Xamarin/etc stuff is not always available.

**UPDATE**
the suggestion of deserializing into `ExpandoObject` as below:

```
dynamic newtonSoftResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
```

seems to work initially, however it fails to deserialize json lists and I couldn't make it backward compatible with System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode() result:

```
string single = "{\"s\":\"String1\",\"f\":\"0.00\"}";
string multiple = "[{\"s\":\"String1\",\"f\":\"0.00\"},{\"s\":\"String2\",\"f\":\"1.23\"}]";
var helpersSingle = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(single);
var helpersMultiple = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(multiple);
var newtonSingle = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(single);
var newtonMultiple = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(multiple);//System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'.
Assert.AreEqual("String1", helpersSingle.s);
Assert.AreEqual("String2", helpersMultiple[1].s);
Assert.IsFalse(helpersSingle is IEnumerable);
Assert.IsFalse(newtonSingle is IEnumerable);//This fails as well as ExpandoObject would implement IEnumerable for its properties
```

Comment: Deserialize to concrete .Net classes with strongly typed properties?

Comment: No, my code is building classes semi-manually picking values one-by-one. I often don't need to deserialize the whole object, so happy with just some of the properties. At this point I'm not looking for suggestions to improve or change my coding practices, all I'm asking is how to either make one class case-sensitive or another class to return typed values. Suggestions for another library that addresses both of these problems are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) with the following helper class:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static object Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return ToObject(JToken.Parse(json));
    }

    private static object ToObject(JToken token)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    expando.Add(prop.Name, ToObject(prop.Value));
                }
                return expando;

            case JTokenType.Array:
                return token.Select(ToObject).ToList();

            default:
                return ((JValue)token).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

In your tests you can do:

```
dynamic result = JsonHelper.Deserialize(json);
```

The result will either be an [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0) or a `List<ExpandoObject>` which should work with most of your tests.  You will have to make an adjustment for tests that check for `IEnumerable` since `ExpandoObject` does implement this interface.  If you need to differentiate between a single object or multiple, you could check for `IList` instead.

Working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n2jI1d

Comment: Excellent! I've had to implement a wrapper class to make it fully compatible with Json.Decode() and support some legacy calls like `newtonSoftResult["intValue"]`, but this helped a lot.

Comment: I've revised my answer to address the single vs. multiple problem.  Hopefully this helps.  I don't have an answer for the `IEnumerable` issue other than adjusting your tests to check for `IList` instead.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've adjusted your code a little as there's no TryAdd method in my environment and it seems to pass subject to the tweaks I need to do again to address Int64 vs Int32 conversions and other compatibility issues. Will check further and accept the answer once it all in place.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it addresses the question and your solution looks very nice and concise. However I will be posting another question as the differences are too great and sometimes unexpected (apart from arrays there are indexing, bigintegers, non-existing properties and so on) to safely transition to NewtonSoft without having to rewrite the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft wraps the JSON Properties.. for various very good reasons I wont get into. You don't need to cast you can just use ***.Value*** i.e ***newtonSoft.intValue.Value***. I should point out that you are still parsing the entire JSON string here using dynamic types because you don't use most of it isn't a good excuse to use dynamic typing. I would highly recommend you not use dynamic types but to each there own.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TypeCastTest() {
  string json = "{\"intValue\":123}";
  dynamic webHelpersResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(json);
  dynamic newtonSoftResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
  Assert.AreEqual(123, webHelpersResult.intValue);
  Assert.AreEqual(123, newtonSoftResult.intValue.Value);
}
```

Comment: This is just as bad as cast for me. My typical use is like this:

`var deserializedResponse = SerializerHelper.DeserializeJson(response);
return decimal.Parse(deserializedResponse.price);`

I don't need the rest of the properties and don't want to replicate the response into strongly typed class — it's a lot of work in itself plus a lot of refactoring once response structure changes for whatever reason.

Comment: Fair enough, either/or @Brians answer is objectively better